Next.js App Router server component error handling
Given a Server Component (or Server Action) that fetches data, how can I access the full error message for server-side logging purposes?
Example:
import os from 'os';
import { PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD } from 'next/constants';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

async function getDataFromServer(): Promise<string> {
  if (process.env.NEXT_PHASE !== PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD) {
    throw new Error('Error from server');
  }

  return Promise.resolve(`OS Type: ${os.type()}`);
}

export default async function Home() {
  const serverData = await getDataFromServer();

  return (
    <p>From server: {serverData}</p>
  )
}

Running this in a "production" version (npm run build, npm run start) results in

An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.

I do not want to expose the actual error message to clients, but I want to log it to a service server-side. Error boundaries are client-side, so they get the sanitized message.
The only way I've found is to wrap every server method in try..catch. I can create a higher-order function to reduce the boilerplate, but is there a way to create a single server-side error handler (without delegating from every catch block)?

In order to access the full error message for server-side logging purposes in a Next.js Server Component or Server Action, you can use a try catch.
import os from 'os';
import { PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD } from 'next/constants';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

async function getDataFromServer(): Promise<string> {
  if (process.env.NEXT_PHASE !== PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD) {
    throw new Error('Error from server');
  }

  return Promise.resolve(`OS Type: ${os.type()}`);
}

export default async function Home() {
  let serverData;
  try {
    serverData = await getDataFromServer();
  } catch (error) {
    // Log the full error message server-side
    console.error('Server error:', error);

    // You can choose to return a fallback value or rethrow the error if needed
    serverData = 'Error fetching data';
  }

  return (
    <p>From server: {serverData}</p>
  );
}


Right, but I want to do this in one place for all pages / server components. Wrapping every component in a try..catch is messy and error-prone.

in order to get all component errors for individual component I think it will be not possible as we need something in order to check for error for the particular component/function like an event
